# Resque Not Selecting Correct Server From Config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque, unicorn

I'm trying moving my Reddis server off to an external box. Have followed the Resque readme on github through.

In development mode, it loads the config just fine and connects to localhost on 6379:

resque.rb initialiser

```
 rails_root = ENV['RAILS_ROOT'] || File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../..'
 rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'

 resque_config = YAML.load_file(rails_root + '/config/resque.yml')
 Resque.redis = resque_config[rails_env]
```

resque.yaml

```
 development: localhost:6379
 playground: redis1.play.xxx.com:6379
 production: redis1.pro.xxx.com:6379
```

However, in playground / production modes, it falls back to development server and doesn't connect. I'm assuming this is because unicorn's not declaring the environment correctly?

If I replace 'development' with 'playground' in the initialiser, it works.

I'm starting unicorn with:

```
 unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E playground -l 8000 -D
```

How can I get it to pick up the correct conf??

Answer (score 0):

Finally sorted although I don't really understand why... Won't accept my own answer for a couple of days if someone wants to interject.

By getting God to manage the service instead of starting / stopping manually, it picked up the correct environment.

Now I'm connecting to a remote redis service with no issues.